# MySQL date finder from today

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of users which has a date field for their birthday:

```
buddy_auto_id    int(11) PK

user_id          varchar(128)

buddy_user_id    varchar(128)

buddy_name       varchar(128)

buddy_bday       date

buddyuser_id     varchar(20)

active           enum('Yes','No')

requestsentby    int(11)

whenrequested    timestamp
```

I'm trying to find the 3 users whose birthdays fall soonest compared to todays date and then display the number of days until their birthday ordered by soonest first.

Is this possible within a SQL query or do I have to pull it out and let PHP do the equation?

Many thanks

Comment: it should be possible with a query. The challenge is to compare a date with the current date while ignoring the YEAR part.

Comment: Its a good question.. I have updated my answer.. please have a look.. that may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with SQL. You need to compare the current date with a birthday expressed as from this year or next year, depending on whether we've past it in the current year.  Once you have this "next birthday" date, use  [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to determine number of days distant from current date.

```
SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(
        # determine date of next birthday by adding age in years to birthday year
        DATE_ADD(buddy_bday, INTERVAL
            YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(buddy_bday)
            # add a year if we celebrated birthday already this year
            +(MONTH(buddy_bday)<MONTH(CURDATE()) OR (MONTH(buddy_bday)=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND DAY(buddy_bday) < DAY(CURDATE())))
        YEAR),
        CURDATE())
    AS days_to_next_bday
FROM user_table
ORDER BY days_to_next_bday
LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

We first need to calculate the next birthday, then order by that value:

```
select *,
    buddy_bday + interval 
        if(
              month(buddy_bday) < month(now()) or 
              (month(buddy_bday) = month(now()) and day(buddy_bday) < day(now())),

              year(now())+1,
              year(now())
        ) - year(buddy_bday) year as next_bday
from buddies order by next_bday - date(now());
```

The long if statement figures out whether the buddy already had his/her birthday this year.

Comment: And for the number of days until next birthday use a param for the long expression ( `@next_bday := long_expression` ) , and `DATEDIFF(@next_bday, now())`

Answer (score -1):

You should use a DAYOFYEAR function. Try this query -

```
SELECT buddy_auto_id , buddy_bday FROM table_name
  WHERE DAYOFYEAR(buddy_bday) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) > 0
  ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(buddy_bday) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW())
  LIMIT 3;
```

So, this query works only for current year.

---

**EDITED query 2:**

This one works for all dates.

```
CREATE TABLE birtdays(
  buddy_auto_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  buddy_bday DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (buddy_auto_id)
);

INSERT INTO birtdays VALUES 
  (1, '2011-10-04'),
  (2, '2011-03-01'),
  (3, '2011-11-29'),
  (4, '2011-11-10'),
  (5, '2011-12-29'),
  (6, '2011-11-30'),
  (7, '2011-12-08'),
  (8, '2011-09-17'),
  (9, '2011-12-01'),
  (10, '2011-12-11');

SELECT buddy_auto_id, buddy_bday
  FROM
    birtdays, (SELECT @day_of_year:=DAYOFYEAR(NOW())) t
  ORDER BY
    DAYOFYEAR(buddy_bday + INTERVAL YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(buddy_bday) YEAR) - @day_of_year
      + IF (DAYOFYEAR(buddy_bday + INTERVAL YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(buddy_bday) YEAR) - @day_of_year > 0, 0, DAYOFYEAR(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-12-31'), '%Y-%m-%d')))
  LIMIT 3;

+---------------+------------+
| buddy_auto_id | buddy_bday |
+---------------+------------+
|             6 | 2011-11-30 |
|             7 | 2011-12-08 |
|            10 | 2012-02-11 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: What about leap years? That may give off-by-one errors. You really do need to compare month and day manually.

Comment: @Francis Avila Yes, you are right. I should rewrite the query. Thanks;-)

Comment: I don't think this new query addresses the problem either. The problem is this: `DAYOFYEAR('1984-04-01') <> DAYOFYEAR('1985-04-01')`  In other words, you can't use `DAYOFYEAR` to compare dates in different years reliably, because you may get different results for the same date in different years.